# ServiceStack Docker architecture

Tags: nginx, docker, servicestack, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if anyone with bigger brains has tackled this.

I have an application where each customer has a separate webapp in Azure.  It is Asp.net MVC with a separate virtual directory that houses ServiceStack.  The MVC isn't really used, the app is 99% powered by ServiceStack.

The architecture works fine, but as we get more customers, we have to manage more and more azure webapps.  Whilst we can live with this, the world of Containers is upon us and now that ServiceStack supports .net core, I have a utopian view of deploying hundreds of containers, and each request for any of my "Tenants" can go to any Container and be served as needed.

I think I have worked out most of how to refactor all elements, but there's one architectural bit that I can't quite work out.

It's a reasonably common requirement for a customer of ours to "Try" a new feature or version before any other customers as they are helping develop the feature.  In a world of lots of Containers on multiple VMs being served by a nginx container (or something else?) on each VM, how can you control the routing of requests to specific versioned containers in a way that doesn't require the nginx container to be redeployed (or any downtime) when the routing needs changing - e.g. can nginx route requests based on config in Redis?

Any advise/pointers much appreciated.

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it isn't Azure-specific we've published a step-by-step guide to publishing [ServiceStack .NET Core Docker Apps to Amazon EC2 Container Service](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs) which includes no-touch nginx virtual host management by [running an Instance of jwilder/nginx-proxy Docker App](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs#log-into-the-new-ec2-instance) to automatically generate new nginx Virtual Hosts for newly deployed .NET Core Docker Apps.

The [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) isn't AWS-specific and should work for any Docker solution that explains how it works in its [introductory blog post](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/).

Using nginx-proxy is a nice vendor-neutral solution for hosting multiple Docker instances behind the same nginx reverse-proxy, but for Scaling your Docker instances you'll want to use the orchestration features in your preferred cloud provider, e.g. in AWS you can scale the [number of compute instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html) you want in your ECS cluster or utilize [Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) where AWS will automatically scale instances based on usage metrics.

Azure's solution for mangaging Docker Instances is [Azure Container Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-intro) which lets you scale instance count using the [Azure acs command-line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-scale).

Comment: Thanks - I read this; the main bit I can't work out is not about SS, but how I would direct traffic to a versioned docker image.  e.g. say I have 3 VMs in a cluster, and each of those is running 8 containers of v1 and 2 containers of v1.1 of the same app.  How would I tell nginx that when it recieves a host-header of "myBetaTestingTenant.MyApp.com" to route these *only* to v1.1 containers.

Comment: @Gumzle We build the Docker image with a different VIRTUAL_HOST environment variable which is what nginx uses to reverse proxy different host names to Docker instances. But to load balance across different VMs you can use a [Route 53 or ELB solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/service-discovery-for-amazon-ecs-using-dns/) or just [Route 53 and DNS Round Robin](https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-aws-route-53-over-elastic-load-balancing/).

Comment: Yes, I guess I could just deploy updated containers with the right VIRTUAL_HOST variable to ensure the right containers are getting the right requests.  Just a shame I'd need to deploy something in order to move a customer from one version to another (albeit "no-downtime" thanks to the watching).

Answer (score 2):

Our company is working on the same thing. We were working with kubernetes and building our own reverse proxy with nodejs. This reverse proxy would read customer settings from a certain cache and redirect you to the right environment.

But Depending on the architecture i would advice to just have 2 environments running with both there relative urls: 1 for production and one for the pilot/test environment. Whenever a customer goes to the pilot environment url he will use the same database but just an upgraded version of the WebApp.

Of course this will not work if working with an ORM and database migrations are included. (Which is probably the case when you are using servicestack)